# Merge incremental data into observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a backend method, which only gets the changed data between a time interval (from, to).
Those incremental changes should be merged into the current data.
But I have no clue, how to merge the incremental changes into the current active data.

```
// will be triggered all N-seconds.
private refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
private last = 0;

data$: Observable<Record[]> = refresh$.pipe(
  switchMap((elapsed: number) => this.fetchIncrementalData(this.last, elapsed),
  // here mergeWithIncrementalChanges() should be called, but how to get the current active data as the first function parameter, which is the latest value of data$??
)

fetchIncrementalData(last: number, elapsed: number): Record[] {
    // calls the webservice which returns only the records (and only the changed properties of the record), which have changed in the specified time interval
    return service.getIncrementalChanges(last, number);
}

mergeWithIncrementalChanges(currentData: Record[], updateData: Record[]): Record[] {
    // merge the new incremental data from fetchIncrementalData() into the current active data.
    ...
    return mergedRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **scan** operator is ideal here.  It allows you to accumulate changes with each emission.  It's kind of like **reduce** but instead of returning a single result, it returns a result with each emission.

```
data$: Observable<Record[]> = refresh$.pipe(
  switchMap((elapsed: number) => this.fetchIncrementalData(this.last, elapsed),
  scan((acc, cur) => mergeWithIncrementalChanges(acc, cur), [] as Record[])
)
```

The example above fetches the incremental data with each emission of refresh.  Each call of scan will then merge the results of the previous call (starting with an initial empty array), and return those results.